# BeautifulSoup gives me unicode+html symbols, rather than straight up unicode. Is this a bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: python, html, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape a website. The website's page renders fine in my browser:

> Oxfam International’s report entitled “Offside!
>   http://www.coopamerica.org/programs/responsibleshopper/company.cfm?id=271

In particular, the single and double quotes look fine. They look html symbols rather than ascii, though strangely when I view source in FF3 they appear to be normal ascii.

Unfortunately, when I scrape I get something like this

> u'Oxfam International\xe2€™s report
>   entitled \xe2€œOffside!

oops, I mean this:

```
u'Oxfam International\xe2€™s report entitled \xe2€œOffside!
```

The page's meta data indicates 'iso-88959-1' encoding. I've tried different encodings, played with unicode->ascii and html->ascii third party functions, and looked at the MS/iso-8859-1 discrepancy, but the fact of the matter is that ™ has nothing to do with a single quote, and I can't seem to turn the unicode+htmlsymbol combo into the right ascii or html symbol--in my limited knowledge, which is why I'm seeking help.

I'd be happy with an ascii double quote, " or "

The problem the following is that I'm concerned there are other funny symbols decoded incorrectly.

```
\xe2€™
```

Below is some python to reproduce what I'm seeing, followed by the things I've tried.

```
import twill
from twill import get_browser
from twill.commands import go

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BSoup

url = 'http://www.coopamerica.org/programs/responsibleshopper/company.cfm?id=271'
twill.commands.go(url)
soup = BSoup(twill.commands.get_browser().get_html())
ps = soup.body("p")
p = ps[52]

>>> p         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe2' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> p.string
u'Oxfam International\xe2€™s report entitled \xe2€œOffside!<elided>\r\n'
```

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_frm/thread/9b7bb3f621b4b8e4/3b00a890cf3a5e46?q=htmlentitydefs&rnum=3&hl=en#3b00a890cf3a5e46

http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/demoroniser/

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/windows-chars.html

```
>>> AsciiDammit.asciiDammit(p.decode())
u'<p>Oxfam International\xe2€™s report entitled \xe2€œOffside!

>>> handle_html_entities(p.decode())
u'<p>Oxfam International\xe2\u20ac\u2122s report entitled \xe2\u20ac\u0153Offside! 

>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', p.decode()).encode('ascii','ignore')
'<p>Oxfam International€™s report entitled €œOffside!

>>> htmlStripEscapes(p.string)
u'Oxfam International\xe2TMs report entitled \xe2Offside!
```

EDIT:

I've tried using a different BS parser:

```
import html5lib
bsoup_parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("beautifulsoup"))
soup = bsoup_parser.parse(twill.commands.get_browser().get_html())
ps = soup.body("p")
ps[55].decode()
```

which gives me this

```
u'<p>Oxfam International\xe2\u20ac\u2122s report entitled \xe2\u20ac\u0153Offside!
```

the best case decode seems to give me the same results:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', p.decode()).encode('ascii','ignore')
'<p>Oxfam InternationalTMs report entitled Offside!
```

EDIT 2:

I am running Mac OS X 4 with FF 3.0.7 and Firebug

Python 2.5 (wow, can't believe I didn't state this from the beginning)

Comment: What does "oops I mean this" mean?  Did your backspace key not work?

Comment: @S.Lott: is there a backspace key in mac?

Comment: @SilentGhost: there's one on each of my macs.  The "oops I mean this" is very, very irritating.  Why not backspace?  What's so important about repeating the same characters in a different markup?  Is it "funny"?

Comment: that was an accident. the first is a blockquote, the second is a code. i thought one of them might show the actual text i wrote rather than rendering symbols. (i thought the code did so in the preview; was surprised to see it look the same after seeing your comment. no need to get get irritated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's one seriously messed up page, encoding-wise :-)

There's nothing really wrong with your approach at all. I would probably tend to do the conversion before passing it to BeautifulSoup, just because I'm persnickity:

```
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.coopamerica.org/programs/responsibleshopper/company.cfm?id=271').read()
h = html.decode('iso-8859-1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
```

In this case, the page's meta tag is lying about the encoding. The page is actually in utf-8... Firefox's page info reveals the real encoding, and you can actually see this charset in the response headers returned by the server:

```
curl -i http://www.coopamerica.org/programs/responsibleshopper/company.cfm?id=271
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2009 13:14:29 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: COMPANYID=271;path=/
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If you do the decode using 'utf-8', it will work for you (or, at least, is did for me):

```
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.coopamerica.org/programs/responsibleshopper/company.cfm?id=271').read()
h = html.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
ps = soup.body("p")
p = ps[52]
print p
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative and gentle response. It does indeed work for me, too.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually UTF-8 misencoded as CP1252:

```
>>> print u'Oxfam International\xe2€™s report entitled \xe2€œOffside!'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
Oxfam International’s report entitled “Offside!
```