# UnicodeEncodeError when inserting Chinese characters into mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, mysql-python

I am using Beautifulsoup to scrape Chinese text from a Chinese website, and I tried to insert the string I scraped into mysql database through MySQLdb in python. But I encountered UnicodeEncodeError when I execute the query. The code is as the following:

```
movie_name_fail = my_beautifulsoup_object.find("div").text
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MOVIE_TABLE VALUES(%s)",movie_name_fail)
```

It gives me the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(256)
```

But when I do

```
print movie_name_fail
```

The Chinese characters can be printed out corrrectly.
And I have already declared

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

as the encoding of my python source file, but it did not work. However, when I typed the same Chinese characters directly into my text editor(I am using sublime text), **it worked pretty well and I am able to insert it into mysql and display it in mysql console correctly**(I have already set the CHARACTER SET of the table in mysql to be utf8):

```
movie_name_success = "超人总动员"
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MOVIE_TABLE VALUES(%s)",movie_name_success)
```

I could not figure out why the bug happened and how it worked. I would really appreciate any help.

**Update**

My python version is 2.7.8, and the MYSQL version is 5.7.11

I pushed my source code to github which should be able to reproduce the error on line 117: "db_cursor.executemany(insert_sql,movie_tuple_list) "

https://github.com/shawnli2010/JHSaver/blob/master/LeTV_scraper.py

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/630099/429982) suggests decoding your page first, before passing into beautiful soup (eg. `html = html.decode('utf-8')`)

Comment: I tried it. It gave me another error:"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 531-533: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Please update with Python version and small, complete example that actually reproduces the error.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I just updated with the information you asked for, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that Python construct add quotes when doing the substitution? It needs to.

Did you establish utf8mb4 for the connection?

Is the table/column `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`?

[More Python notes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)

I suggest utf8mb4 instead of utf8 because Chinese has some characters that need 4 bytes.

Comment: I add "charset" and "use_unicode" arguments for "db = MySQLdb.connect()", based on the python notes you provide,and it worked! Thank you so much!!